# How show data in TableView from two joined entities in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have two entities

```
public class StatusEntity {
private long id;
private String type;
private String code;
private String desc;}

public class BoxesEntity {
private int id;
private int boxId;
private StatusEntity OperationId;}
```

And my controller code

```
@FXML
private TableView<BoxesEntity> BoxesTableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<BoxesEntity, String> boxIdColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<StatusEntity, String> boxOperStatusColumn;

@FXML
void initialize() {

    IDBService service = new DBService();
    List<BoxesEntity> list = service.getAllBoxes();

    boxIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("boxId"));
    boxOperStatusColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("OperationId"));

    BoxesTableView.getItems().setAll(list);

}
```

As result I have TableView with correct **boxId**, but I don't know how to show StatusEntity's **desc** property. How I can access StatusEntity's **desc** property?

Comment: a) a tableView can hold items of a single type - which might be Object at the broadest: if so you can provide custom valueFactories that return properties based on type b) java naming conventions, please!

Comment: Can’t you just do `boxOperStatusColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue().getOperationId().getDesc()));`?

Comment: @James_D Nice, but is not defining Properties in model class, in this case StatusEntity and BoxesEntity better in the terms of performance? Are we creating new Properties every time we add an object to the table?

Comment: @Wortig No, the opposite is true. If you create the property in the model, you will have a property in memory for every item in the table’s backing list. Here there is only a property for each cell.